# What does it mean with "surge pricing in effect" at Stellar-Core?

Tags: stellar-core, scp, error

As I tested my private network by flooding transaction (around 60TPS) via Horizon using JS-sdk, SCP errored. The only abnormalty that I observed was:

> [Herder WARNING] surge pricing in effect! 142

Any thoughts on what it means? I traced [some code](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/d888470fce9e08eeb68fbd9c5641ecff33d691f1/src/herder/TxSetFrame.cpp#L157-L187) and still no idea..

And it seems this warning pops out with a value >= 101 (above example=142).

```
2018-03-29T19:03:55.103 GBIEA [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=138207, prev=bcc7c3, tx_count=100, sv: [  txH: 724ce5, ct: 1522321434, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2018-03-29T19:03:55.424 GBIEA [Ledger INFO] Closed ledger: [seq=138207, hash=e38cbd]
2018-03-29T19:03:59.788 GBIEA [Herder WARNING] surge pricing in effect! 140
2018-03-29T19:04:00.178 GBIEA [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 138206 : {"agree":4,"disagree":0,"fail_at":2,"hash":"31e0fa","missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE"}

2018-03-29T19:04:00.188 GBIEA [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=138208, prev=e38cbd, tx_count=100, sv: [  txH: adc0c0, ct: 1522321439, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2018-03-29T19:04:00.603 GBIEA [Ledger INFO] Closed ledger: [seq=138208, hash=b3e3da]
2018-03-29T19:04:04.788 GBIEA [Herder WARNING] surge pricing in effect! 142
2018-03-29T19:04:05.116 GBIEA [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 138207 : {"agree":4,"disagree":0,"fail_at":2,"hash":"31e0fa","missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE"}

2018-03-29T19:04:05.120 GBIEA [SCP ERROR] Exception in processEnvelope state: {
   "slots" : {
      "138209" : {
         "ballotProtocol" : {
            "ballot" : "(1,[  txH: 7d6788, ct: 1522321444, upgrades: [ ] ])",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you linked to seems to be removing the transactions from a transaction set that have the lowest fees, until the set size equals [100](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/d888470fce9e08eeb68fbd9c5641ecff33d691f1/src/ledger/LedgerManagerImpl.cpp#L71).

This corresponds with [the documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#transaction-limits) which states:

> Each Stellar node usually limits the number of transactions that it will propose to the network when a ledger closes. If too many transactions are submitted, nodes propose the transactions with the highest fees for the ledger’s transaction set. Transactions that aren’t included are held for a future ledger, when fewer transactions are waiting.

Comment: Thanks man. Any idea if the transaction volume constantly exceeds this number? I saw that Stellar could handle >1000TPS, whereas my private network (4 nodes, only different network passphrase) could not even handle 100TPS. The stellar-core process simply died out silently in the above manner.

Comment: That's a good question @cesarmak. I don't know, I only read the source & the docs. Perhaps the TPS measure is actually the number of operations? If so, 50 txns of 20 ops each would make 1k "TPS", for example, but I don't have any operational experience and I'm just guessing.

Comment: That's also my wild guess... FYR I am doing stress test and 60-80TPS (duration=days) is ok with 100% success rate, but only testing with 1Op in 1 Tx. Maybe I should try with 20Ops later.

Answer (score 1):

The number of transactions per ledger is governed by a network wide setting that you need to change on a private network:

look up the `upgrades` endpoint on the [commands](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks Mr Nicolas! I was unaware of this. Do you have any idea about the default value "[maxtxsize=NUM]" or the value for the live network?